# Solution of pendulum linked to Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I've been working through a question about the equation of motion of a pendulum. 
I have to now solve the equation of the form: 
$$u'^2=u^3+au+b,$$ 
 where $a=(\frac{g^2}{l^2}-\frac{c^2}{3})$ and $b=(\frac{g^2c}{3l^2}-\frac{2c^3}{27})$, using separation of variables.

So, I have separated the equation to get: $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u^3+au+b)}}\,\mathrm du=\int1\,\mathrm dt$$

Now, I could just integrate this directly and attempt a solution, but the next part of the question asks what the solution has to do with the Weierstrass $\wp$-function. Is there a trick we can use to find the solution?

Comment: That issue here is that your integral can't be 'integrated directly.' It's elliptic.

Comment: Weierstrass elliptic function arises at the inversion of the integral on the left, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Integral_equation)

Comment: I've re-read the question and I think this part does just want me to write the integral down. So for the next part, it asks what the P-function has to do with the standard solution of a pendulum. I'll have a think about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is straight because your $u$ corresponds to a Weierstrass P-function.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Differential_equation